# Unable to install MySQL Workbench on CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to install MySQL Workbench on my Linux machine, however, not able to do so. I'm getting the below error:

No match for argument: mysql-workbench-community

Error: Unable to find a match: mysql-workbench-community

Below are the steps I performed untill the error:

```
sudo dnf -y update
Last metadata expiration check: 0:11:50 ago on Sun 04 Jun 2023 12:47:19 PM IST.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!

[root@localhost piyush.choudhary]# sudo dnf -y install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql80-community-release-el8-5.noarch.rpm
Last metadata expiration check: 0:12:44 ago on Sun 04 Jun 2023 12:47:19 PM IST.
mysql80-community-release-el8-5.noarch.rpm       11 kB/s |  15 kB     00:01    
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                        Arch        Version     Repository         Size
================================================================================
Upgrading:
 mysql80-community-release      noarch      el8-5       @commandline       15 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package

Total size: 15 k
Downloading Packages:
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                        1/1 
  Upgrading        : mysql80-community-release-el8-5.noarch                 1/2 
  Running scriptlet: mysql80-community-release-el8-5.noarch                 1/2 
   Warning: native mysql package from platform vendor seems to be enabled.
    Please consider to disable this before installing packages from repo.mysql.com.
    Run: yum module -y disable mysql

  Cleanup          : mysql80-community-release-el8-4.noarch                 2/2 
  Verifying        : mysql80-community-release-el8-5.noarch                 1/2 
  Verifying        : mysql80-community-release-el8-4.noarch                 2/2 

Upgraded:
  mysql80-community-release-el8-5.noarch                                        

    Complete!
[root@localhost piyush.choudhary]# rpm -qi mysql80-community-release
Name        : mysql80-community-release
Version     : el8
Release     : 5
Architecture: noarch
Install Date: Sun 04 Jun 2023 01:00:05 PM IST
Group       : System Environment/Base
Size        : 8853
License     : GPLv2
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Thu 06 Apr 2023 04:58:49 PM IST, Key ID 467b942d3a79bd29
Source RPM  : mysql80-community-release-el8-5.src.rpm
Build Date  : Thu 06 Apr 2023 04:52:41 PM IST
Build Host  : pb2-el8-01.regionaliad02.mysql2iad.oraclevcn.com
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
Vendor      : MySQL
URL         : http://dev.mysql.com
Summary     : MySQL repository configuration for yum
Description :
Package for installation of setup/configuration files required for
installation of MySQL packages by yum.
[root@localhost piyush.choudhary]#  ls /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community*
/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community-debuginfo.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo.rpmnew
/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo.rpmsave
/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community-source.repo
[root@localhost piyush.choudhary]# cat  /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo 
# Enable to use MySQL 5.5
[mysql55-community]
name=MySQL 5.5 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.5-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

# Enable to use MySQL 5.6
[mysql56-community]
name=MySQL 5.6 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

# Enable to use MySQL 5.7
[mysql57-community]
name=MySQL 5.7 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.7-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql80-community]
name=MySQL 8.0 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-connectors-community]
name=MySQL Connectors Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-tools-community]
name=MySQL Tools Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-tools-preview]
name=MySQL Tools Preview
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-preview/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-cluster-7.5-community]
name=MySQL Cluster 7.5 Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-cluster-7.5-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-cluster-7.6-community]
name=MySQL Cluster 7.6 Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-cluster-7.6-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql

[mysql-cluster-8.0-community]
name=MySQL Cluster 8.0 Community
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-cluster-8.0-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
[root@localhost piyush.choudhary]# sudo dnf makecache timer 
Metadata cache refreshed recently.
[root@localhost piyush.choudhary]# sudo dnf install mysql-workbench-community
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64  0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64  457 kB/s |  17 MB     00:37    
CentOS-7 - Base                                 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
CentOS-7 - Updates                              0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
CentOS-7 - Extras                               0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    


 No match for argument: mysql-workbench-community
 Error: Unable to find a match: mysql-workbench-community
```

I'm also trying the official document and taking help from this platform but I'm still getting the error "Unable to find a match".

Request everyone to help me sort out this error.

Update:
Now, I'm getting the below error when trying to follow the mysql official document.

```
"mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do"

[root@localhost piyush.choudhary]# wget https://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm

--2023-06-04 15:22:29--  https://repo.mysql.com/mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
Resolving repo.mysql.com (repo.mysql.com)... 49.44.153.198
Connecting to repo.mysql.com (repo.mysql.com)|49.44.153.198|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11196 (11K) [application/x-redhat-package-manager]
Saving to: ‘mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm’

100%[======================================>] 11,196      --.-K/s   in 0s      

2023-06-04 15:22:30 (165 MB/s) - ‘mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm’ saved [11196/11196]

[root@localhost piyush.choudhary]# md5sum mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
659400f9842fffb8d64ae0b650f081b9  mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
[root@localhost piyush.choudhary]# yum install mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Examining mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm: mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch
mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm: does not update installed package.
Error: Nothing to do
```

And when trying to uninstall the package, it shows no packages marked for removal.

```
   [root@localhost piyush.choudhary]# yum remove mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
No Match for argument: mysql80-community-release-el7-7.noarch.rpm
No Packages marked for removal
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, CentOS 7 was based on RHEL 7 so you won't possibly be able to install packages for RHEL 8.

Comment: I see, let me try for version 7 then

Comment: Hi Alvaro, now I'm getting the error "No package mysql-workbench available.
Error: Nothing to do"

Comment: Are you sure you want to install workbench, the graphical user interface, on what sounds like a server?

Comment: Yes, it is required for my work at the moment. Can you help?

Comment: Does https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-mysql-workbench-on-centos-7 help?  If not, you can always build from source

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, better to follow official document.

Answer (score -1):

It's solved - I re-installed the packages and it's working fine.

Comment: Please do not self-answer questions that are essentially not-reproducible; since there are no other answers, better delete the thread altogether.